# Google Open Id with HTML 5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-openid

I want to use Google Open Id in my web application.  I just embedded code found on the google developer site into my application. I want to retrieve at least the name of the person who has logged in, but the code is not replying.  Please help me with this.
Even an alert in that function will also do for me...[You can find the same code at the following link.](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/)

```js
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        alert('Test');
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      };
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="838209778730-9ci5dv2ouvj275fo80bmpc7vof6ufqn8.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn();" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script> javascript function here
        </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**data-onsuccess** parameter should contain just function name, not a call.

Here is the correct declaration of g-signin2:

```
 <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
```